# Fetch Look up fields additional values in Search Results Display Template

Tags: sharepoint-search

We have a scenario where we want to create a dynamic URL with the help of Look Up additional ID field value.
We have created Managed Properties for Look up but the additional fields of Look up columns do not have any values even after doing full crawl.

Please share if anyone has done similar things in the past.